# Custom functionality of inner components on setting userControl "isEnabled"

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've created a silverlight UserControl with some inner elements that I'd like to custom change when the controls isEnabled property is set (for example changing some inner Image controls to look greyed out). With other properties I set up a DependencyProperty and do the code there, but this doesn't called for isEnabled (I assume because it's already declared). The code is below;

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("isEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(BreadcrumbElement), null);

    public bool isEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
            if (value)
                Chevron.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/ChevronRight.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                Chevron.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Resources/ChevronRight_Disabled.png", UriKind.Relative));

        }
    }
```

I'd like to use isEnabled instead of something else, so is there a way to get this to function correctly? Thanks :)

Comment: Please add xaml where you bind IsEnabled.

Answer (score 2):

Hook onto `Control.IsEnabledChanged` Event and write your code in the handler of this event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.isenabledchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx